# Exception from Tracker recompute function

Tags: meteor

I have a template helper that access a collection in my app., but I have turned off reactivity:

```
Template.homeBoxGroupsTpl.helpers({
    boxes: function () {
        return Boxes.find({},
            {
                sort: {
                    order: 1
                },
                reactive: (Session.get("homeCanvasTplReactive") || false)
            }
        );
    }
});
```

After I insert a new element on my page, that in turn updates the collection, Meteor will throw an error in the browser console:

```
    Error: Exception from Tracker recompute function: reporters.js?1429904535194:67 
Error: Error: Bad index in range.getMember: 16
        at DOMRange.getMember (http://tidee-vm/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:586:11)
        at http://tidee-vm/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2727:45
        at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (http://tidee-vm/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:593:12)
        at Object.Blaze.Each.eachView.onViewCreated.eachView.stopHandle.ObserveSequence.observe.changedAt (http://tidee-vm/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2721:17)
        at http://tidee-vm/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde:313:21
        at Function._.each._.forEach (http://tidee-vm/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
        at diffArray (http://tidee-vm/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde:299:5)
        at http://tidee-vm/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde:147:9
        at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (http://tidee-vm/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:593:12)
        at http://tidee-vm/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde:121:15
```

Any ideas how to debug this, or is it a Meteor issue?

Comment: What is in line 67 of your reporters.js?

Comment: reporter.js is simply reporting the error "Exception from Tracker recompute function".

Answer (score 0):

Meteor's error messages are horrible in all browsers but Chrome, because Meteor expects stack traces to include the error messages, but this is only done by Chrome. I hate to say this, but you'll probably have to use Chrome when debugging a Meteor app. :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the solution, but I too encountered the same error, and was able to solve for my case, so posting it, hoping it helps you debug the issue (although this hardly seems to be of any help). The cause was use of `.length`. I had a large array (name of array: data), and to make it short (decrease length of arrray), I was assigning `data.length = 5`, which was somehow causing the error, and meteor helper did not work as expected. **Removing that line worked for me**, and I accomplished shortening of array by a for loop, and storing first five elements in a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem too :(

I was able to resolve it by giving unique names to `Tempaltes`, its corresponding `Helpers`object's methods in .js file and `Mongo DataBase` object(s) names.

Hope it might work for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting this error from it saying `ReactionProduct.selectedVariant()` is `null` on one of Meteor's cycles.

I just handled the `null` case with:

```js
if (ReactionProduct.selectedVariant() === null) {
  return;
}
```

and it's working out for me.